# Google Appscript makeCopy : HOw to make deepcopy of the spreadsheet

Tags: google-apps-script

I have used makeCopy function to take monthly backup of the spreadsheet, However, the latest changes of the current spreadsheet are getting carried to backed up copy. 
I would like to restrict the latest changes only to the active spreadsheet only. Could someone help me with this, please?

Comment: Please share your code, the screenshots of what you are getting and a clear visual explanation of your expected outcome

Answer (score 1):

If the changes happens because referenced data you can convert all data in your spreadsheet into simply not-referenced data this way:

```
SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheets().forEach(s => 
  s.getDataRange().setValues(s.getDataRange().getDisplayValues()));
```

It convert all functions into displayed results of these functions.

Of course it makes sense to do only with a copied spreadsheet.